# What's the difference between nullptr and literal '0' and NULL and '(void*)0' and '\0'

Tags: c++, null, literals, nullptr

I need to know what're the differences between all of those literals:

- '\0'
- nullptr
- NULL
- 0
- (void*)0

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Yeah, sorry I will edit the question

Comment: `'\0'` is the nul character literal while `0` is an integer literal.